# Sentence fragments as modifiers: "self-sacrifice incarnate, the 10th Doctor wavered..."?

Tags: idioms, adjectives, sentence-fragments, appositives

I was recently asked to choose which of following two excerpts sounded better:

> Emotionally vulnerable and *incarnate of self-sacrifice*, the Tenth Doctor wavered between romantic and intensely protective relationships with his companions.
>
> Emotionally vulnerable and *self-sacrifice incarnate*, the Tenth Doctor wavered between romantic and intensely protective relationships with his companions.

I'm fairly certain this is a Dr. Who reference.

I argued that, even if the first one was changed to read "Emotionally vulnerable and incarnation of self-sacrifice," the second one was a better choice as "self-sacrifice incarnate" is an (compound?) adjective, where "incarnation of self-sacrifice" is a noun (right?).

But, even though I'm pretty sure the second choice is the better of the two, I can't explain why. In fact, I can't even explain what to call this whole thing. The programmer in me won't let me rest until I know what it is, how it should be used and, potentially/if necessary, why. I've spend the last 30 minutes Googling away for an answer to no avail -- primarily because I'm not sure for what it is I'm searching.

So, to summarize:
Which wording should be used and why? Moreover, what are these types of descriptors called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjective *incarnate* is used in an **appositional** or **appositive** adjectival phrase in your first example:

> ? *Emotionally vulnerable and incarnate of self-sacrifice,* the Tenth Doctor wavered between romantic and intensely protective relationships with his companions.

The adjectival phrase modifies the subject, *the Tenth Doctor*. It is similar to simple sentences like this:

> *Extremely disappointed,* she turned around and left.

This construction is normally only used when the phrase is longer than one or two syllables, so you would not normally see the following in a novel, even though it is perhaps not strictly ungrammatical:

> ? Angry, she left the room.

---

As to the word *incarnate*, this adjective is usually limited in use to a very specific sequence:

- [person] **is** [property or archetype] **incarnate** — *(used as a postpositional adjective)*
- [person] **is the/an incarnate of** [property or archetype] — *(used as a noun; less common outside a religious context)*

So you could say *she is the devil incarnate*, meaning "she is the devil in (new) flesh", the word *incarnate* strictly meaning "embodied, (made) in the flesh". The adjective modifies a noun that is not normally present in the flesh, such as an abstract quality or a dead person. A few more examples:

> Breivik is Hitler incarnate.
>
> He is the incarnate of Vishnu.
>
> My mother is loquacity incarnate.
>
> The Tenth Doctor is self-sacrifice incarnate.

---

The word *incarnation* can mean a thing or person incarnate, and you would normally use it with an article:

- [person] **is a/the incarnation of** [property or archetype]

The same applies to using *incarnate* as a noun followed by *of x*. A nominal/noun phrase—a phrase that functions as a noun and can replace a noun in a sentence—can also be used in apposition, as in to this simple sentence:

> An experienced teacher, she immediately spotted the cheater's tiny note on his pen.

It is, again, not normally used with a noun phrase that is just a single noun. Your example lacks an article, which I would consider compulsory, because *incarnation* is a countable noun here:

> Emotionally vulnerable and *the/an* incarnation of self-sacrifice, ...
>
> Emotionally vulnerable and *the/an* incarnate of self-sacrifice, ...

However, the construction *x incarnate* is probably the most common one, and the one I would recommend, even though the other two are also perfectly acceptable:

> Emotionally vulnerable and **self-sacrifice incarnate**, the Tenth Doctor wavered between romantic and intensely protective relationships with his companions.

This has nothing to do with the adjectival or nominal nature of the appositional phrase *per se*, because both kinds of appositional phrase are perfectly fine in general.

Comment: It may be worth noting that "X incarnate" is generally used where X is not a carnal being (even "Hitler incarnate" because he's dead); and that it's a set phrase and *incarnate* in this use always appears as a post-positive adjective. I rather like "loquacity incarnate" and will endeavour to use it!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks! You are graciousness incarnate. I've added "dead person" and "postpositional".

Comment: The restriction on the _appositional / appositive adjectival phrase_ (though I'd call it an absolute adjectival phrase) is perhaps weight- rather than word-count-dependent: ?Angry, she left the room. // Flabbergasted, she left the room.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Right, replaced "single word" with "one or two syllables. I would not call such a phrase absolute, because it modifies something, in casu the subject. An absolute phrase has to be vaguely adverbial in my book.

Comment: [Absolute adjectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective) do not belong to a larger construction (aside from a larger adjective phrase), and typically modify either the subject of a sentence or whatever noun or pronoun they are closest to; for example, _happy_ is an absolute adjective in "The boy, happy with his lollipop, did not look where he was going." [Wikipedia]. I accept this label, so in '_Emotionally vulnerable and self-sacrifice incarnate_, the Tenth Doctor ...' the compound adjectival phrase is absolute (syntactically unattached) but does indeed modify 'the Tenth Doctor'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't see how "syntactically unattached" and "modifies" can be compatible. It is to me syntactically attached and therefore not absolute, but apparently some people would use "absolute" for this. Appositional or appositive is the term I am used to. It is also weakly parenthetical.

Comment: Parentheticals _are_ syntactically unattached. They can be omitted without leaving the residue ungrammatical AND without altering the meaning of the matrix sentence. However, they modify something in the matrix sentence. Absolute constructions form a subset of parentheticals.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Why should a parenthetical phrase be syntactically unattached? And how can something that is unattached modify something? Parenthesis creates some syntactical "distance" between a phrase and its surroundings, that is true; but an absolute phrase is almost completely cut off, which is really something different. A non-defining relative clause is also weakly parenthetical (I would say just as weakly as an appositional phrase), but not at all absolute. *The soldiers, who had been close to mutiny, were now plundering the city.*

Comment: The proof that an appositional phrase is syntactically "attached" is that you can't move it away from that which it modifies. An absolute (nominal) phrase is like an adverbial subordinate clause, an appositional phrase is like a relative clause. There is a difference. // You said this: *Parentheticals* are *syntactically unattached. They can be omitted without leaving the residue ungrammatical AND without altering the meaning of the matrix sentence.* But almost all normal adjectives can also be left out without ungrammaticality and without changing the meaning of what remains.

Comment: Emotionally vulnerable and self-sacrifice incarnate, the Tenth Doctor wavered ... = The Tenth Doctor, emotionally vulnerable and self-sacrifice incarnate, wavered ... // "The boy, happy with his lollipop, strolled down the path." = "Happy with his lollipop, the boy strolled down the path." = "The boy strolled down the path, happy with his lollipop."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Both are appositional in my book. They can come before or after the noun phrase. But anyway, are you saying you perceive no difference between the phrases in *the doctor being insufferable, she turned around and left the room* and *being insufferable, the doctor made her turn around and leave the room*?

Comment: They're different parentheticals. 'Being insufferable' =/= 'The doctor being insufferable.'>>  Apposition is defined thus: apposition n. ... 3. a grammatical relation between expressions, usu. consecutive, that have the same referent **and the same relation to other elements in the sentence**, as between 'our first president' and 'Washington' in 'Washington, our first president, was born in Virginia'. [bolding mine] Deleting either leaves a grammatical and sensible residue, with no change of meaning – merely less detail. Contrast "Happy with his lollipop strolled down the path."

Comment: @Edw: Okay, so the problem we have here is that we use a different definition both for the term *absolute* and for *appositional*. I assure you that my definition of *absolute* is widely used, but I will from now on assume you are using in a different (and no doubt respectable) way to mean any parenthetical phrase. To get things straight, a non-restricting relative clause is also absolute, right? As to *apposition*, Collins says *2. (Linguistics / Grammar) a grammatical construction in which a word, **esp** a noun phrase, is placed after another to modify its meaning.* ...

Comment: So it can be an adjective, as in my definition. An example from the Wiki article: *You're simply the best, better than all the rest*. My reason for including certain adjectival phrases is that the construction is just identical: *a cold but intelligent woman, she was not swayed by his plea...* v. *cold but intelligent, she was not swayed by his plea...* But I will assume you are limiting *apposition* to noun phrases in the future. Then we can all be happy, it's all just a choice of words, in the end.

Comment: No – I'd also consider 'Iodine sublimes, passes from the solid state direct to the gaseous, at x degrees' to be an example. I've just found that I'm using the term 'apposition' in the narrowest sense discussed by Quirk (17.66) where they label this strict sense 'full apposition'. This demands equivalent statements. Quirk goes on to discuss other wider usages allowed by some grammarians for 'apposition' which, rather than equivalences (X, that is to say Y,), involve attribution (X, a/the Y,), exemplification (X, for example Y,), and particularisation (X, in particular Y,). English!

Comment: The linguist Hockett (1955:99-102) affirms that appositives 
have the shared linguistic feature that is the double head, and each head must belong to the same form class. The latter criterion is refuted by other grammarians; both Meyer and Quirk et al.(1987:101-2 and 1985:1303 )